# SQL Server look for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and I have multiple server connections and I need to know where a specific stored procedure exists in every server which contains multiple databases!

Looking for a query to run on each server

Comment: Are you using SQL Management Studio to connect to MySQL or do you connect to multiple RDMS and want the query to work on both MySQL and MSSQL? Have you looked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or any form of searching? Any code with errors?

Comment: no im using query directly in sql server management studio

Comment: You'll probably have to iterate sys.databases using a cursor and then checking each of the databases if the procedure is there (sys.procedures or sys.objects)

Comment: thank you for your help, but that wont work for me, since each server contains hundreds of databases, is there any other way ? by looking in each server?

Comment: sp_msforeachdb should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little script that you could run on each server.
I know that it uses a `while` loop, which is generally not preferred, someone might be able to improve on it.

Run the script from the `master` database.

**SQL Query:**

```
set nocount on

declare @procname varchar(150) = '<SPROCNAME_TO_FIND>'  -- SET THIS TO THE STORED PROCEDURE NAME YOU ARE LOOKING FOR

declare @alldbonserver table
      ( databasename varchar(150),
        doneflag     bit )

declare @foundtbl table
      ( countcol int,
        dbname   varchar(150) )

declare @errortbl table
      ( dbname varchar(150) )

insert @alldbonserver
     ( databasename,
       doneflag )
select sdb.name,
       0
  from sys.databases sdb

declare @curdbname varchar(150),
        @sqlcmd    varchar(max)

while exists (select 1
                from @alldbonserver
              where doneflag = 0)
begin
  select top 1
         @curdbname = databasename
    from @alldbonserver
   where doneflag = 0

   select @sqlcmd = 'select distinct 1, ''' + @curdbname + ''' as dbname from ' + @curdbname + '.sys.objects where type = ''P'' and name = ''' + @procname + ''''

   begin try
     insert @foundtbl
          ( countcol, dbname )
     exec(@sqlcmd)
   end try
   begin catch
     insert @errortbl
     values ( @curdbname )
   end catch

   update @alldbonserver
      set doneflag = 1
    where databasename = @curdbname
end

select dbname as 'Databases with stored procedure'
  from @foundtbl

select dbname as 'Unable to access databases'
  from @errortbl

set nocount off
```

**Sample output:**

```
Databases with stored procedure
-----------------------------------------
MainDatabase
SomeOtherDatabase

Unable to access databases
-----------------------------------------
model
ReportServer$SQLTemp
VeryPrivateDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put this together on SQL2012.  It should return all Stored Procs on a Server for a given name.  If you leave @SPName blank, you will get all of them.

The Query utilizes sys.all_objects so you could easily change it to work the same for tables, functions, any or all db objects.

```
DECLARE @SPName VARCHAR(256)
SET @SPName = 'My_SP_Name'

DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR
 SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR

SELECT name
FROM sys.databases

CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (DBName VARCHAR(256),
    SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
    SPName VARCHAR(256))

OPEN @getDBName
FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SET @varSQL = 'USE [' + @DBName + '];
 INSERT INTO #TmpTable
 SELECT '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName,
 SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
 name AS SPName
 FROM sys.all_objects
 WHERE [type] = ''P'' AND name LIKE ''%' + @SPName + '%'''
 EXEC (@varSQL)

FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
END

CLOSE @getDBName
DEALLOCATE @getDBName

SELECT *
FROM #TmpTable
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSMS, you could create a server registration group that contains all of the servers you connect to, right click on the group and run this query against the group: `exec sp_MSforeachdb 'select * from [?].sys.procedures where name=''<your_name_here>'''`

This query will enumerate each of the databases on each of the servers in the group (note: the single quotes are like that for a reason...)